# Similar .rdata functionality in Python?

Tags: python, r

I'm starting to learn about doing data analysis in Python.

In R, you can load data into memory, then save variables into a `.rdata` file.

I'm trying to create an analysis "project", so I can load the data, store the scripts, then save the output so I can recall it should I need to.

Is there an equivalent function in Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're looking for is binary serialization.  The most notable functionality for this in Python is `pickle`.  If you have some standard scientific data structures, you could look at HDF5 instead.  JSON works for a lot of objects as well, but it is not binary serialization - it is text-based.

If you expand your options, there are a lot of other serialization options, too.  Such as Google's Protocol Buffers (the developer of `Rprotobuf` is the top-ranked answerer for the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag on SO), Avro, Thrift, and more.

Although there are generic serialization options, such as `pickle` and `.Rdat`, careful consideration of your usage will be helpful in making I/O fast and appropriate to your needs, especially if you need random access, portability, parallel access, tool re-use, etc.  For instance, I now tend to avoid `.Rdat` for large objects.

Answer (score 3):

[`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)
[`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)